Change public access settings for Account in S3, not change in create S3
I change the Block Public Access settings for this account settings in the AWS S3. Enable first 2 options and disable the last 2.

But when I go to Create Bucket option, there it might be inherit this settings, but there it show all disabled.

Is there any way to make sure Create Bucket inherit the Account settings?

As per AWS doc:

Account level settings override settings on individual objects.
Configuring your account to block public access will override any
public access settings made to individual objects within your account.

So, if you have the Block Public Access settings for this account enabled, turning on any of the four option will apply even if the bucket has them disabled. The AWS console also highlights the same:

Hope this answers your question.
